# ORA-00959: tablespace 'X' does not exist while running impdp command

Tags: database, oracle

I want to import a dmp file using the following command

```
impdp c##user3/user3 full=y REMAP_SCHEMA=HR:c##user3 DIRECTORY=testdirec DUMPFILE=test.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE nologfile=y TRANSFORM=OID:N exclude=user ignore=y
```

but a got this error

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"C##USER3"."TABLE1" failed to create with error: ORA-00959: tablespace 'HR_A' does not exist
```

Please any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Observation: you are importing into a common user schema. Are you also importing into a Container Database (CDB)? Application data should *never* be stored in a container database, only in pluggable databases.

Comment: @pmdba Hmm.. I am new to oracle and database administration if you please have any good tutorial to do it in a better way it would be great  !

Comment: Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/administration.html, and here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/index.html,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tablespace that the source table was located in does not exist in the target database. You need to either create the HR_A tablespace or remap that tablespace to one that does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Basically add REMAP_TABLESPACE to data pump import,
like:

`impdp hr REMAP_TABLESPACE=tbs_1:tbs_6 DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=employees.dmp`

or using PL/SQL

`DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_remap (v_hdnl,'REMAP_TABLESPACE','TESTING123','TESTING321');`